# Unexpected behavior with masonry effect on rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript, jquery-masonry

I got inspiered by Makenzie Child [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcnfFS_DS8) and [github repo](https://github.com/mackenziechild/pinterest_clone/tree/master/app/assets/javascripts) to create a masonry effect on my rails app.

I have a little problem, when I visit the page, the behavior is not the expected one, all the boxes are below each others, and if I reload they take the good behavior... I would like that the good behavior could display when we arrive on the page.

I don't know any javascript please dont be mad at me :)

this is the progresses.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  $('#progresses').imagesLoaded ->
    $('#progresses').masonry
      itemSelector: '.box'
      isFitWidth: true
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

views/progresses/index.html.slim

```
.container
  .section
    .row
       .col-xs-12
        h1.text-gold 
          |Work In Progress  [
          = @progresses.count 
          | ]
  hr
  #progresses.transitions-enabled
    - @progresses.each do |progress|
      .box.panel.panel-default
        = link_to (image_tag progress.main_image.url), progress
        .panel-body
          h4.text-gold = progress.title.upcase
          h5 = progress.date
          small = truncate(progress.content, length: 150)
```

Thanks for your help,

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it works when you reload the page makes me suspect this is a turbolinks problem.

> Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Instead of letting the browser recompile the JavaScript and CSS between each page change, it keeps the current page instance alive and replaces only the body and the title in the head.

So you'll visit the page using a link within your application, the javascript doesn't reload. But when you do a refresh on the page, everything is fetched again including the javascript causing the script to execute.

### **Solution 1**

This also means things like `$(document).ready(function(){` won't work because this only fires on initial load. Try something like this out:

```
ready = ->

  $('#progresses').imagesLoaded ->
  $('#progresses').masonry
    itemSelector: '.box'
    isFitWidth: true

$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

I'm assuming you're using rails 4, this won't work in rails 5. I've used the following question for information and there are ways described to do this in rails 5: [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Turbolinks will trigger the `page:load` event when a new page is loaded.

### **Solution 2**

Another solution might be using [`jquery-turbolinks`](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks) gem.

It's easy to use. Add `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'` to your gemfile. Then add `//= require jquery.turbolinks` to your application.js. This **has** to go between `//= require jquery` and `//= require jquery_ujs`. So in your case:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require masonry/jquery.masonry
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

If any of this doesn't work, you might want to disable turbolinks for a moment to see if turbolinks is actually the problem.
You can do this by replacing the `<body>` tag in your `application.html.erb` with the following: `<body data-no-turbolink="true">` Just note that disabling turbolinks for your whole application isn't something you'll want. There are clean solutions to disable it for a specific page.

**EDIT**

If the following solution works for you, you can try this instead of the code I gave in **solution 1**:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {

  ...your javascript goes here...

});
```

In my opinion this is a lot cleaner and I've read that it should work from rails 4.2 and above. Notice the difference: `turbolinks:load` instead of `page:load`.

Comment: Thanks for the time you spend answering me !
I tried all and actually it worked with doing this : `ready = ->

  $('#progresses').imagesLoaded ->
  $('#progresses').masonry
    itemSelector: '.box'
    isFitWidth: true

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)` But I  have a  new problem ... my boxes are overclaping now....

Comment: ```$(document).on('turbolinks:load')``` worked for me on Rails 6

Answer (score 1):

So I go it to work with

```
ready = ->

  $('#progresses').imagesLoaded ->
    $('#progresses').masonry 
      itemSelector: '.box'
      isFitWidth: true

$(document).on('turbolinks:load', ready)
```

As I mentionned in my first comment my boxes were overclapped because I missed the indentation on the line `$('#progresses').masonry`
Now It works perfectly 
Thanks again for all

Comment: This worked for me. I believe this would be the correct answer as of Rails 5.